# Detect last row in dynamically created edittexts inside a list

Tags: java, android

I have an app that creates a row of 3 edittexts dynamically and places them inside a list so that i can "play" with their values.For example if i want to call the price in the first row i just do pret[0]. For short, it's kind of a shopping list with a field for product name, quantity and price. I already set it up to detect when the text is being changed (text watcher) so that it calculates the total in real time so i know when people are writing on the edittexts but i can't know when they're typing in the last row of edittexts.

What I want now is this: when the last row is clicked/focused/has text entered in it to call produsnou() and automatically create a new row of Edittexts. As i said, my problem is that I don't know how to detect when they're typing or clicked or focused on the last row.
This is the way I create new rows of editexts.

```
public void produsnou() {
    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setHint("Produs");
    l1.addView(et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    et.setId(997);      

    LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
    et2.setHint("Cantitate");
    et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    et2.setId(998);

    allcant.add(et2);
    l2.addView(et2);
    et2.addTextChangedListener(this);

    LinearLayout l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
    et3.setHint("Pret");
    et3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    l3.addView(et3);
    et3.setId(999);
    allpret.add(et3);
    et3.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

I did this and it doesn't work :
`public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        LinearLayout l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        if (hasFocus && 
                l3.getChildAt(l3.getChildCount() ) == view) {
            produsnou();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `OnFocusChangeListener` to achieve this. In the listener, you can find out, if the view is the last one in the `LinearLayout` like this:

```
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus && 
            linearLayout.getChildAt(linearLayout.getChildCount() - 1) == view) {
        produsnou();
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird,it doesn't work,it doesn't automatically add another row of edittexts.

Comment: So `produsnou()` won't get executed? Is there another view in the LinearLayout as the last element?

Comment: Nope,there isn't.I have a linearlayout,inside of it there are 4 linear layouts(one for the first column of products,the second for quantity,the third for prices and the fourth for buttons and textviews. Do i have to replace view with something ?

Comment: No, `view` is the view, which gained or lost focus. `linearLayout` has to be the one, which directly contains the `EditText`.

Comment: It works,your code was good,i made a mistake but fixed it now,heh.Thanks !!